# Object Context in Child component LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

How should get the object context on child component. We have LWC as parent child on record page. I can able to read the record context this.ObjectApiName in parent component but not  in child component.

Is there a way to pass from parent to child as  this.objectAPiName can be initiliazed in connected call back or in any event call only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child, you use:

```
@api objectApiName;
```

And in the parent, you set the value:

```
<c-child object-api-name={objectApiName}
```

These values should be available in the connectedCallback.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Appreciate your answer. i tried this little differently.  I think what you r mentioning is pass objectApiName itself to child objectApiName.I will try it out.  I was passing parent objectApiName  to a variable on child...